# Pattern matching for different tense of word regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings

```
L  = ["Your acccount has beed deleted by the administrator", "Trouble while deleting account",
     "Please delete my account"]
```

I want to find if any form of the word `delete` is present in the string.
other forms/tense of delete could be `deleted,deleting,deletion,delete`

similarly for another word say `face` , other forms/tense of face could be `facing`.
Is there any way to identify such scenarios using regex??

AS a sample word:

I am looking to write such a pattern so that if i give `delete` in pattern and do regex.search

`re.search(r'\b(delete)\b',"I am deleted you")`

It should give me a match of the word `'deleted'` as well.

for eg:

```
for i in L:
    if re.search(r'\b(delete)\b',i) != None:
        print(i)

"Your acccount has beed deleted by the administrator", 
"Trouble while deleting account",
"Please delete my account"
```

Comment: why not put all the possible words inside regex?

Comment: Like delete,face.... there could be 1000 such words in english vocabulary, and multiple combinations of such words, That would be too hectic of a process

Comment: Using NLP tools makes it trivial, say, with spacy, it will be as easy as `[t.text for t in nlp("Your acccount has beed deleted by the administrator") if t.lemma_ == 'delete']` that yields `['deleted']`. You could use `if t.lemma_ in my_word_list`, too.

Comment: What you want to do is called *lemmatizing* and a regex is not the right approach because no natural language is that regular. Think about *go/went*. Follow the excellent advice about using NLP tools instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex is not actually the right tool you are looking for, and [BoarGules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769668/pattern-matching-for-different-tense-of-word-regex#comment118030823_66769668) illustrated it with `go/went` well.

If you want to solve the issue, you need an NLP tool like [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage).

Here is an example:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
text = "Your acccount has beed deleted by the administrator"
doc = nlp(text)
[t.text for t in doc if t.lemma_ == 'delete']
## => ['deleted']
```

If you have a list of lemmas, replace `if t.lemma_ == 'delete'` with `if t.lemma_ in your_list`.

Answer (score 1):

English is a terrible language to do this for.

```
/\b[dD]elet(e|es|ed|ion|ing)\b/
 ^^                         ^^   zero-width word boundary
   ^^^^                          "d" or "D"
           ^ ^  ^  ^   ^   ^     any of this list
```

You do need to worry about initial caps, and perhaps all-caps.  The "delete" example works for *most* verbs ending with "e".

```
/\b(see|saw|seen|sees)\b/
```

There are plenty of irregular verbs.

```
/\bleap(|s|t|ed|ing)\b/
```

Usage is turning "leapt" into "leaped".  Or both are acceptable (depending on who you listen to).  Or should that be "to whom you listen".

And some words differ between British and American English.

And if you need to grab the word found, then add parens at the appropriate place.  (Or do like I did on `\b(see|...)\b`